# Second Jest test always fails - spyOn called twice

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I can't fathom what I'm doing wrong here. In my suite of tests the second one always fails. So I duplicated passing tests, changed the order etc and still the second one always fails.

Command:

```
jest --verbose --runInBand
```

Setup:

```
{
    "clearMocks": true,
    "resetMocks": true,
    "restoreMocks": true,
    "resetModules": true,   
    "maxConcurrency": 1,
}
```

Tests:

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../../server");
const { sequelize } = require("../../sequelize");  

describe("API routes tests", () => {

  afterEach(() => {
     jest.clearAllMocks();
     jest.restoreAllMocks();
   });

  describe("GET /api/my-route", () => {

    it("Test 1", async () => {
      // create a mocked response
      const mockedResponse = [{ log: 1 }, { log: 2 }];

      // spy on sequelize.query
      const query = jest
        .spyOn(sequelize, "query")
        .mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);

      // make the request
      const response = await request(app)
        .get("/api/user-activity-logs")
        .query(defaultQueryParams);

      // assertions
      expect(query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body).toHaveProperty("groupedLogs", mockedResponse);
      query.mockClear();
    });

    it("Test 2", async () => {
      // create a mocked response
      const mockedResponse = [{ log: 1 }, { log: 2 }];

      // spy on sequelize.query
      const query = jest
        .spyOn(sequelize, "query")
        .mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);

      // make the request
      const response = await request(app)
        .get("/api/user-activity-logs")
        .query(defaultQueryParams);

      // assertions
      expect(query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // <== fails with 2
      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body).toHaveProperty("groupedLogs", mockedResponse);
      query.mockClear();
    });

    it("Test 3", async () => {
      // create a mocked response
      const mockedResponse = [{ log: 1 }, { log: 2 }];

      // spy on sequelize.query
      const query = jest
        .spyOn(sequelize, "query")
        .mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);

      // make the request
      const response = await request(app)
        .get("/api/user-activity-logs")
        .query(defaultQueryParams);

      // assertions
      expect(query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body).toHaveProperty("groupedLogs", mockedResponse);
      query.mockClear();
    });

  });
});
```

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in the tests and not in the code? Can you add `expect(query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);` at the start of each test? If it fails, you know, it's the test configuration. If it doesn't fail, it seems like the server queries the database twice for some reason.

Comment: The configuration works for me. I can't reproduce the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yc69se?file=src%2Fapp.spec.js

Comment: I like where you're going with this. Maybe it is something to do with SuperTest which I'm not aware of.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] and add it to your question? I think the problem is related to your code. Does `app` have a state? Do you expect the tests to reset the state? Do you use a database for tests? Is the number of queries dynamic?

Comment: My assumption is that each test has a new instance of app and therefore is a clean state. I'm not sure that's right...

Changing the tests from async to using 'done' and combining with `.then` fixes it!

e.g. 
request(app).get("/api/route").query({}).then((res) => {
          expect(query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
          expect(res.status).toBe(200);
          done();
});

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. `app` is imported once and never reset. If you want a new instance, use a constructor.

Comment: Gotcha, still would love to know why only the second test and all others work fine. Thanks for your help. Feel free to write an official response so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: Your question isn't answerable. This behavior is caused by code you haven't added to your question. Your posted code works as expected, as you can see in my [mcve] in my second comment. Adding random changes may fix your problem, but don't answer your question.

Comment: So your MRE works because it's not actually sequelize, but appreciate your help, it made me look at the issue differently and i found the answer quite quickly after that

Comment: It's usually not necessary to mock the whole module. It's necessary in your special case because you're doing something in your code that you don't want to show us.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out I just needed to mock the whole sequelize module and that meant each test has a "clean" slate to start from, just using spyOn wasn't enough.

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../../server");
const { sequelize } = require("../../sequelize"); 

// mock sequelize
jest.mock("../../sequelize"); 

describe("API routes tests", () => {
  // previous code
});
```